# i am working on a browser game. I was working on the replay system. i made a replay button but it I can't click it

Tags: html, css

I am working on a replay system in my browser game I made a replay button that calls the replay function , the problem is I can't click it, I tried setting the z-index to 1000 but it didn't work even I put it after every element in the document but it  didn't work, any help would be appreciated

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xi6Hs.png)

code :

```
    <style>
        #retry {
            z-index: 1000;
        }
    </style>

    <button id="retry" onclick="replay()">retry</button>
```

any one can help ?

Comment: Can you please share more code of the surrounding HTML? Without seeing the placement of the button, it's hard to understand why the button is not being displayed.

Comment: How do you know the click wasn’t acted on?  What does replay do and are you certain there are no JavaScript errors? (Check your browsers devtools inspect console)

Comment: there is no thing wrong in the script even i made the function play it self after a while so i can work on the replay system while i am waiting for an answer on stackoverflow